# .htaccess Rewrite rule http error 500.51

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis-7

I am trying to redirect all urls to index.php and then include pages based on the url, so I am trying to achieve user-friendly URI's basically.

The site is hosted using IIS.
Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This has been placed in the root directory for the site.

I tried to provide a screenshot of the error, but my reputation is too low.
However, this is the error I am provided with

```
HTTP Error 500.51 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The condition's expression "{Map1:{REQUEST_URI}}" is not valid.
```

To get this error, I am using the following url 'http://192.168.1.66/hello'.

Any help understanding the issue will be much appreciate; I have tried to provide as much information as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Your IIS is using a .htaccess file? In my experience it has always used a web.config. You sure you don't also have a web.config file?

Comment: Thank you Chris, that is the answer. I now have it working :) haha